# Isolate a FlywayException only for a migration error

Tags: sql, exception, migration, flyway

In a flyway migration a FlyWayException can be throw according to differents cases : during a migration failure, if the given database url can not be found etc.
Everytime it's a FlyWayException with a JdbcSQLException as cause. But in my app I'd like to isolate these cases in order to provide differents behaviors.

Is there any way to do this ?

I can see that a JdbcSQLException contains a SQLState, maybe it can be a solution, but I don't know if it's the best one.

Answer (score 0):

It is never good to parse out SQL exceptions as they may change from version to version of the database. I would submit a feature request to Flyway to have specific exceptions instead of one generic FlyWayException: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues.